# How to get the inverse of a linear interpolation in R

Tags: r

I went through many solutions for that problem, but could not find a reliable automated one. Please find below a detailed self-suficient description.

These are the data:
data.txt

```
x y
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 1
```

Plotting as a scatter plot:

```
t=read.table("data.txt",header=T)
plot(t$x,t$y,"l")
```

You will see a peak, my question is now: assuming I am happy with the linear interpolation, what is the width at half maximum of that "curve"? So for which values x0 of x I have f(x0)=max(y)/2, where f is the linear interpolation. I tried with approxfun and some kernel density, but I do not want to smooth my data.

Any input is very welcome.

Comment: having two '4' values in your x data is evil.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am guessing OP means 5.

Comment: @nograpes: I'd hope so as it doesn't fit well with 'inverse'.

Comment: Ups, you are right, that should be a 5

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a new pair of data:  `xfine<-seq(1,5,by=.01)` and `yfine` from using `predict` on `xfine` ; then something like `xfine[which(abs(yfine-mean(y))< .02)]`   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function to do what you want, assuming your data are unimodal, here using linear interpolation:

```
# FUNCTION TO INFER FWHM USING LINEAR INTERPOLATION
fwhm = function(x, y) { 
  halfheight = max(y)/2
  id.maxy = which.max(y)
  y1 = y[1:id.maxy]
  y2 = y[id.maxy:length(y)]
  x1 = x[1:id.maxy]
  x2 = x[id.maxy:length(y)]
  x.start = approx(x=y1,y=x1, xout=halfheight, method="linear")$y # or without interpolation: x[which.min(abs(y1-halfheight))]
  x.stop = approx(x=y2,y=x2, xout=halfheight, method="linear")$y # or without interpolation: x[which.min(abs(y2-halfheight))+id.maxy]
  fwhm = x.stop-x.start
  width = fwhm/(2*sqrt(2*log(2)))
  return(list(fwhm=fwhm, width=width))
  }

# GAUSSIAN PEAK FUNCTION WITH MODE AT u, WIDTH AT INFLECTION POINT w (FWHM=2.355*w) AND PEAK HEIGHT h
gauspeak=function(x, u, w, h=1) h*exp(((x-u)^2)/(-2*(w^2)))

# EXAMPLE
x = seq(0,200,length.out=1000)
y = gauspeak(x=x, u=100, w=10, h=100)
fwhm(x=x, y=y)
# $`fwhm`
# [1] 23.54934
# 
# $width
# [1] 10.00048
```

You could also use the `spline()` function instead of `approx()` to do cubic spline interpolation instead of linear interpolation. And if your data were unimodal but noisy you could smooth your data first using `smooth.spline()` (maybe on a `log(y+1E-20)` scale if your data are strictly positive, after which you can backtransform to the original scale).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of better ways of doing this, but here is one solution. It would be easier if we knew how you did the interpolation in the first place.

```
# Extend your line for testing
y<-c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3)

# Split into linear segments.
segments<-c(1,diff(diff(y)))!=0
seg.points<-which(c(segments,TRUE))

# Calculate desired value
val<-max(y)/2

# Loop through and find value
res<-c()
for(i in 1:(length(seg.points)-1)) {
  start<-y[seg.points[i]]
  end<-y[seg.points[i+1]]
  if ((val>=start & val<=end) | (val<=start & val >=end)) {
    slope=(end-start)/(seg.points[i+1] - seg.points[i])
    res<-c(res,seg.points[i] + ((val - start) / slope))
  }
}
res
# [1] 2.5 3.5 6.5
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer! In the first place I simply used the type="l" option, then expressfun(). I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: This helps me with my data, which is not monotonic increasing. Thanks a lot!